# Как сделать запрос в базу данных со встроенной процедурой и входным параметром в YII2

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, yii, stored-procedures

Со стороны базы дали данные параметры:

Наименование встроенной процедуры: `get_info`
Входной параметр `@product_vs varchar(32)`

Набор возвращаемых данных:

```
deal -             Сделка
order_name -       Заказ
```

Я ранее не имел дело с хранимыми процедурами, но пытался вызвать по следующему коду:

```
$result = $db->createCommand("CALL get_info(:product_vs)")
    ->bindValue(':product_vs',$name)
    ->queryAll();
```

Верно ли составлен сам запрос, чтобы вернуть значение?

YII возвращает ошибку:

> :SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.
> The SQL being executed was: CALL get_info('2211229247701-0040')

Comment: `exec get_info @product_vs = :product_vs` скорее всего будет

Comment: @teran огромное Вам спасибо за наводку, исправил запрос на EXECUTE get_info :product_vs и всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $db->createCommand("EXECUTE get_info :product_vs")
    ->bindValue(':product_vs',$name)
    ->queryAll();
```

запрос был составлен не корректно, спасибо пользователю @teran за подсказку!